# character set conversion

Tags: php

i wanna convert to original string of â€œCoolâ€  ..Origingal string is `cool` . (' is backquote)

Comment: Super. What have you tried so far, what's not working for you?

Comment: i need to convert to ``cool``

Comment: http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you just forgot to [specify the character encoding properly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.2).

Because `â€œ` is what you get when the character `“` (U+201C) encoded in UTF-8 (0xE2809C) is interpreted with a single-byte character encoding like [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (default character encoding in some browsers) where 0xE2, 0x80, and 0x9C represent the characters `â`, `€`, and `œ` respectively.

So just make sure to specify your character encoding properly. Or if you actually want to use Windows-1252 as your output character encoding, you can convert your UTF-8 data with [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding), [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv) or similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a wide variety of character encoding functions in PHP, especially if you have access to the [multibyte string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php). (mb_string is thankfully enabled on most PHP installs.)

What you need to do is convert the encoding of the original string to the encoding you require, but as I don't know what encoding has been used/is required all I can suggest is that you could try using the [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) function, possibly after using [mb_detect_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) on the original string.

Incidentally, I'd *highly* recommend attempting to keep all data in UTF-8, (text files, HTML encoding, database connections/data, etc.) as you'll make your life a lot easier this way.